# How would I go about making a linkvertise wrapper

Tags: python, discord, discord.js, discord.py

I want to make a discord bot which lets me paste a link and it returns with the link wrapped under linkvertise. For example in discord I would type *linkvertise https://google.com and it would send me a linkvertise link that makes you go through all the linkvertise steps then redirects you to https://google.com. Basically a linkvertise api? I have not included any code because I literally don't know where to start. As I don't know anything about API's.

```
[Linkvertise website](https://linkvertise.net/dashboard)
[Discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/)
[Discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
```

Comment: Well to start with you've got to choose one, either js or python to use. What do you understand the most. Also I don't get this? What is linkvertise? You meand like markdown of a link [like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61333174/how-would-i-go-about-making-a-linkvertise-wrapper-in-js-or-python)
If so you can do that in discord, therefore you example is right but it'll have to be an embed especially in embed description or field values if i got what you're asking for correct

Comment: I know js better, but also am willing to learn discord.py if it can't be done in javascript.

And no, linkvertise is a url shortener that redirects you to a link. I want to be able to type my link into discord and it converts it into a linkvertise shortened link. If that makes sense.

Comment: You can use the developer tools of your browser to try figuring out what endpoints get called to create the shortened link.  You could also try reaching out to that company to see if they have a public API.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late response, I'm working on this and you need to generate a key then upload to their api.